# Зачем включают несколько тегов <script></script>? Область видимости же одна и та же

Tags: javascript

Такой подход можно увидеть на многих сайтах. Это просто для удобства?

Comment: такие теги могут вставляться автоматически. Плюс некоторые скрипты можно выполнять сразу, а некоторые нужно поместить в конце документа

Comment: Кодерам лень порядок наводить - надо деньги зарабатывать ;)

Comment: А зачем программисты код размазывают по модулям? можно же всё в один файл... вот только такая фигня получится!

Comment: @Akina, вообще, количество модулей может не коррелировать с количеством файлов